# How to connect to website using oauth2 WITHOUT using omniauth?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth-2.0

I'm building a web app and i am trying to connect to mapmyfitness website. unfortunately the omniauth gem for mapmyfitness is outdated and no longer works.. how would i go about connecting to the website without using omniauth?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Oauth2](https://github.com/intridea/oauth2) gem.

Here is usage from the page:

```
client = OAuth2::Client.new('client_id', 'client_secret', :site => 'https://example.org')

client.auth_code.authorize_url(:redirect_uri => 'http://localhost:8080/oauth2/callback')
# => "https://example.org/oauth/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=client_id&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080/oauth2/callback"

token = client.auth_code.get_token('authorization_code_value', :redirect_uri => 'http://localhost:8080/oauth2/callback', :headers => {'Authorization' => 'Basic some_password'})
response = token.get('/api/resource', :params => { 'query_foo' => 'bar' })
```

Comment: do you know of anywhere that i could look to see a setup example?